# google formula to call function using array index

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array

I has this simple google app script :

```
function test() {
  var myarr = new Array(2)
  myarr[0] = new Array(5)
  for(i=0; i<5 ; i++) {
    myarr[0][i]=i
  }
  myarr[1] = "test"
  
  return myarr
}
```

using formula 'test()' with correct result :

[image]

question : is it possible using google formula to grab just the array element using index ? I tried this formula but got error :

```
=test()[0]
```

What is the proper syntax ?

Actually , in google script, I can use **'return myarr[0]'** to get the integer array but how to use index in google formula ?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, is this your expected result? For example, in the case of your showing script, `=INDEX(test(),1)` returns `0,1,2,3,4`. `=INDEX(test(),1,3)` returns `2`. [Ref](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242) But, I'm not sure whether this is your expected result. So, I posted it as a comment. if I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: @Tanaike yes, that's i'm looking for. Pls post the answer.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. From your reply, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to retrieve the elements in an array returning from a custom function `=test()`, I would like to propose using [`INDEX`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242). When this is used, a sample formula is as follows.

```
=INDEX(test(),1)
```

- In this case, `0,1,2,3,4` is returned.

```
=INDEX(test(),1,3)
```

- In this case, `2` is returned.

#### Reference:

- [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242)